# SAML failed to verify signature

Tags: python, xml, saml, saml-2.0, xml-signature

I am using [PySaml2](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2) to implement a SAML service provider.

When I receive a payload (base64 `SAMLResponse`), my server fails to accept it with an error `SignatureError('Failed to verify signature')`.

The part which is failing is the call to the XMLSec lib: `xmlsec1 --verify --enabled-reference-uris empty,same-doc --enabled-key-data raw-x509-cert --pubkey-cert-pem /path/to/cert.pem --id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:Assertion --node-id ... --output /path/to/out.xml /path/to/payload.xml`.

However, I am using the certificate that the IdP has sent me and I can see in the `cert.pem` passed to the call above that it is indeed the correct certificate which is passed to `xmlsec1` (the same as in the payload itself).

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_d9e74668-c20d-43ea-9952-fb129adec5c2" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-11-02T15:10:46.745Z" Destination="..." InResponseTo="_4606cc1f427fa981e6ffd653ee8d6972fc5ce398c4">
    <saml:Issuer>...</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_d3f5b2cb-b7d8-4844-9c0f-46e83ba6a7df" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-11-02T15:10:46.745Z">
        <saml:Issuer>...</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_d3f5b2cb-b7d8-4844-9c0f-46e83ba6a7df">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>...</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>...</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>... Here the certificate base64 ...</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">lui@gmail.com</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2021-11-02T15:15:46.745Z" Recipient="..." InResponseTo="_4606cc1f427fa981e6ffd653ee8d6972fc5ce398c4"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2021-11-02T15:10:46.745Z" NotOnOrAfter="2021-11-02T15:15:46.745Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>...</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">lui@gmail.com</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Luis</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Lui</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Luis Lui</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">431b0975-c262-4a9c-ab6c-95297efadedb</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

What could be wrong?

Edit: Below is the base64 encoded XML payload as received:

```
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
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to debug because the XML you posted does not include the cert, digest and is modified.

XML can be difficult to check when it is posted to a web site.  Its impossible when its been modified.  Please generate another file from a test system and send it again.  Base64 encoding it first before attaching it would be good too.

You could also try the --trusted-pem /path/to/cert.pem option

Update:

With the new base64

Using https://samltool.io/ shows that the Response is Signed not the assertion so the following would work:

xmlsec1 --verify --trusted-pem cert.pem --enabled-reference-uris empty,same-doc --enabled-key-data raw-x509-cert --pubkey-cert-pem cert.pem --id-attr:ID Response --output out.xml tmp.xml

This also works with XML::Sig and https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml

I have not used PySaml2 so it is possible it has a bug but if not it should work now with the correct cert to verify

Comment: Right. I attached the base64 XML to my post.

Comment: Thanks for the base64 I checked with https://tools.chilkat.io/xmlDsigVerify.cshtml and XML::Sig and neither the digest not the signature matched.  Are you able to install Saml Decoder in your browser.  Grab the base64 from that in the off chance that something modified it after the browser received it

Comment: I updated the base 64 below in my post with a new one that is the actual payload received by the server.

Using this tool http://www.dotnetsnip.com/online-saml-signature-validator-tool, it is accepted (the previous one wasn't), but it is still rejected by your tool and by my lib.

Do you have any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: That seems to validate fine with XML::Sig:     Reference Digest:  TEyNVGKNwBxzLK4spLA/N7nwB27e/OGfsvbJYjZjIIM=
    Calculated Digest: TEyNVGKNwBxzLK4spLA/N7nwB27e/OGfsvbJYjZjIIM= xmlsec does not validate it so I will take a closer look this evening - likely I used incorrect options for xmlsec1

Comment: This works - you were trying to validate the signatuire of the Assertion which is not signed.  The Response is signed: xmlsec1 --verify --trusted-pem cert.pem --enabled-reference-uris empty,same-doc --pubkey-cert-pem cert.pem --id-attr:ID Response --output out.xml tm
p.xml