# Signature Error with xmlsec on Windows with django_saml2_auth

Tags: django, azure, single-sign-on, saml, xmlsec

I am following this [tutorial](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/contents/setup.html) to set up a SSO Login on Django. I have installed the xmlsec library from this [link](https://www.zlatkovic.com/projects/libxml/index.html) and everything seems correct but when testing the endpoint with Azure it throws this error:

```
check_sig: ['C:\\Users\\user\\code\\project-backend\\env\\Scripts\\xmlsec.exe', '--verify', '--enabled-reference-uris', 'empty,same-doc', '--enabled-key-data', 'raw-x509-cert', '--pubkey-cert-pem', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpg9oixidy.pem', '--id-attr:ID', 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:Assertion', '--node-id', 'xxxxxxx', '--output', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp4q_a_mb0.xml', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpybj2a3vf.xml']
correctly_signed_response: Failed to verify signature
Signature Error: Failed to verify signature
XML parse error: Failed to verify signature
Internal Server Error: /sso/acs/
Internal Server Error: /sso/acs/
```

I've tried it on a Unix system and It works fine.

Comment: [Problems while implementing SSO using Django SAML2 Auth and AzureAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916491/problems-while-implementing-sso-using-django-saml2-auth-and-azuread), [SAML failed to verify signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830027/saml-failed-to-verify-signature) and [Signature validation failed](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml/issues/166)